# React Native - double ListViews Rendering simultaneously on function call

Tags: android, listview, autocomplete, react-native

I made an autosuggest on TextInput using a ListView. I have put the lists and the input fields in a view and set flexDirection property to row. When i input in one field the list of the other field also gets rendered. I was a separate field using the same functions. But it does not get rendered. and changing the flexDirection to row also does not give this issue. how do i make it render lists specific to its input field. here is my code for views and the functions related..

----------------- code for view--------------

```
<View style={styles.float}>
            <View style={[styles.flex]}>
              <Text style={styles.modalLabels}>Tags</Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                defaultValue={this.state.fillTags}
                onChangeText={(id) => this.search(id, 'tags')}
                underlineColorAndroid='#bcbcbc'
              />
              <ListView
                style={[styles.listview]}
                dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.searchedTags)}
                renderRow={(key) => this.renderList(key, 'tags')}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={[styles.flex]}>
              <Text style={styles.modalLabels}>Location</Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                defaultValue={this.state.fillLocation}
                onChangeText={(id) => this.search(id, 'location')}
                underlineColorAndroid='#bcbcbc'
              />
              <ListView
                style={[styles.listview]}
                dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.searchedLocation)}
                renderRow={(key) => this.renderList(key, 'location')}
              />
            </View>
</View>
```

----------- functions---------------------

```
autofill = (item,key) => {
    if(key === 'rider'){
      this.setState({fillRider: item.name, searchedRiders: []})
    }
    else if(key === 'tags'){
      this.setState({fillTags: item.name, searchedTags: []})
    }
    else if(key === 'location'){
      this.setState({fillLocation: item.name, searchedLocation: []})
    }
  }

  renderList = (item, key) => {
    const renderItem = (
      <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text
            style={styles.searchText}
            onPress={() => this.autofill(item,key)}>
            {item.name}
          </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
    if(key === 'rider'){
      return renderItem
    }

    else if(key === 'tags'){
      return renderItem
    }
    else if(key === 'location'){
      return renderItem
    }
  }

  search = (searchedText, id) => {

    if(id === 'riders'){
      var searchResult = riders.filter(function(rider){
        return rider.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchedText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
      this.setState({searchedRiders: searchResult, searchedTags: [], searchedLocation: []})
    }
    else if(id === 'tags'){
      var searchResult = tags.filter(function(tags){
        return tags.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchedText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
      this.setState({searchedTags: searchResult, searchedLocation: [], searchedRiders: []})
    }
    else if(id === 'location'){
      var searchResult = location.filter(function(location){
        return location.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchedText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
      this.setState({searchedLocation: searchResult, searchedRiders: [], searchedTags: []})
    }
  }
```

Comment: Also it would e great if someone told me how to remove the 'empty section header' warning while using the ListView.

Comment: still looking for answer.....

Answer (score 0):

To remove the 'empty section header' warning, add the following props in your listview:

enableEmptySections={true}

So your ListView will look like:

```
<ListView
                style={[styles.listview]}
                enableEmptySections={true}
                dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.searchedLocation)}
                renderRow={(key) => this.renderList(key, 'location')}
              />
```

Comment: Thanks. I just saw that it is mentioned in the docs and the warnings. My Bad. 
Still, thanks

Comment: I should have provided you the link too. Please upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code:

```
autofill = (item,key) => {
    if(key === 'rider'){
      this.setState({fillRider: item.name, searchedRiders: []})
    }
    else if(key === 'tags'){
      this.setState({fillTags: item.name, searchedTags: []})
    }
    else if(key === 'location'){
      this.setState({fillLocation: item.name, searchedLocation: []})
    }
  }
```

You are updating dataSources(searchedTags, searchedLocation) for two ListViews. The problem is with:
else if condition.

Unless the dataSource is updated simultaneously, it won't be reflected in View.

Provide the UI of your double ListView so that I can provide you assistance with JSX code.

Comment: I have provided the UI the code for view in my question i guess. Also please note, when i remove flexDirection from the container view and they are aligned along column then they are rendered separate and work fine